# Xamarin: Portable Library. Where do I check which device can use this library

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

When I create the Portable Library Project I have no choice of what device this library support. I went to Project Options->General I can select a list of profile but I can't deselect the checkbox otherwise it show error message. I want my Portable library work on IOS and Android so I can add a NGraphics package but I can't add to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a current list of all PCL Profiles and what platforms they support here: http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY

Not all packages will support all target platforms properly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PCL library that supports Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS (you'll get a bunch of compatible ones, i.e. Windows 8.1). Or change it by going to right click on project in Solution Explorer, Library and then click on Change... button.
Then you can install NGraphics from NuGet.

Comment: i did create PCL library but nothing in the creation asked me about compatible on what devices

Comment: What IDE? Visual Studio or Xamarin studio?

Comment: i use xamarin to develop

Comment: Go to Project/project options/build/general and select PCL 4.5 -  Profile78 for example.

Comment: Because it supports same minimal API set. So you don't loose anything while you support more platforms.

Comment: But in android, I can use System.IO.File etc, but not in PCL is that because some platform doesn't support: would that be the IOS not support it

Comment: There are nuget packages that add that support or use inversion of control. File operations aren't supported in PCL. PCL is a set of API, not all of them.